# I want to convert file data into 3d dictionary using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, parsing

Like I want this type of dictionary by reading file:

```
table = {
0: {'A': '1',   'B': '2',   'C': '3'},
1: {'A': '4',   'B': '5',   'C': '6'},
2: {'A': '7',   'B': '8',   'C': '9'}
}
```

or this will be enough.

```
table = {
{'A': '1',   'B': '2',   'C': '3'},
{'A': '4',   'B': '5',   'C': '6'},
{'A': '7',   'B': '8',   'C': '9'}
}
```

I have a file lets name file.txt which has data like

```
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I am trying but i dint get the result this following is my try:
it gives me output {'A': '7', 'B': '8', 'C': '9'}
I know its obvious it will not give me 3d dict but I don't know how to get there.

```
array=[]
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       array = line.split()
       break #it will give me array=['A','B','C']


v=[]
dic = {}
for i in range(0,len(array)):
        for line in open("file.txt"):
            x=0
            v = line.split() 
            dic[ array[i] ] = v[i]    
print(dic)
```

Comment: It seems like you want `table` to be a _list_ of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following code:

```
table = {}

with open("file.txt") as f:
    headers = next(f).split()  # get the headers from the first line
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        row = {}
        for j, value in enumerate(line.split()):
            row[headers[j]] = value
        table[i] = row

print(table)
```

You should get format like this:

```
{
    0: {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'},
    1: {'A': '4', 'B': '5', 'C': '6'},
    2: {'A': '7', 'B': '8', 'C': '9'}
}
```

---

If you only want the inner dictionaries and not the outer structure, you can use a list instead of a dictionary to store the rows:

```
table = []

with open("file.txt") as f:
    headers = next(f).split()  # get the headers from the first line
    for line in f:
        row = {}
        for j, value in enumerate(line.split()):
            row[headers[j]] = value
        table.append(row)

print(table)
```

This will give you the following output:

```
[
    {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'},
    {'A': '4', 'B': '5', 'C': '6'},
    {'A': '7', 'B': '8', 'C': '9'}
]
```

Comment: I like your version too without any module!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Pandas`

```
# Python env: pip install pandas
# Anaconda env: conda install pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('file.txt', sep=' ')
table = df.to_dict('index')
print(table)

# Output
{0: {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3},
 1: {'A': 4, 'B': 5, 'C': 6},
 2: {'A': 7, 'B': 8, 'C': 9}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use just built-in modules, you can use `csv.DictReader`:

```py
import csv

with open("data.csv", "r") as f_in:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f_in, delimiter=" ")
    # if the file countains floats use float(v) instead int(v)
    # if you want values just strings you can do:
    # data = list(reader)
    data = [{k: int(v) for k, v in row.items()} for row in reader]
    
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
[{"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}, {"A": 4, "B": 5, "C": 6}, {"A": 7, "B": 8, "C": 9}]
```

Comment: @Corralien I put a comment to the answer that if the file contains floats then `float()` should be used.

Comment: Both examples of OP's required output have the column values as strings. Agreed that having them as *int* or *float* would make more sense but it's not what she wants

Comment: @Fred I've added second comment. If OP wants just string, he can do just `data = list(reader)`

Answer (score 1):

DictReader from the *csv* module will give you what you seem to need - i.e., a list of dictionaries.

```
import csv

with open('file.txt', newline='') as data:
    result = list(csv.DictReader(data, delimiter=' '))
    print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '4', 'B': '5', 'C': '6'}, {'A': '7', 'B': '8', 'C': '9'}]
```

**Optionally:**

If you have an aversion to module imports you could achieve the same objective as follows:

```
result = []

with open('file.txt') as data:
    columns = data.readline().strip().split()
    for line in map(str.strip, data):
        result.append(dict(zip(columns, line.split())))

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '4', 'B': '5', 'C': '6'}, {'A': '7', 'B': '8', 'C': '9'}]
```

Comment: @Corralien Could do but it would produce a different result. But thanks for the tip anyway

Comment: @Corralien Let's wait for OP to clarify **exactly** what she does want before jumping to conclusions. At the moment there are several people who seem to think she wants a list of dictionaries